# What are the grammatical similarities between Mongolian and Japanese?

Tags: grammar, japanese, mongolian

Are there any native speakers of Mongolian that have learned Japanese, or vice versa? Any tips on learning the grammar would be appreciated. I'm not expecting anyone to have learned both languages but if so, your input would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japonic_languages Mongolian and Japanese are in different language groups.